# Rendering both layout and view, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render

I have next mistake: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect`

here

```
respond_to do |format|
            format.html {
                render layout:"productView"
                render "show2"

            }
          ajax_respond format, :section_id => "user_tab_comments"           
            format.js
        end
```

So I want to render both layout and view, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you are rendering them both as 2 separate responses to one request. One request -- one response. You need to stuff them in a single `render`-directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this instead of double render:

```
   render :show2, layout: 'productView'
```

And layout page should be under app/views/layouts/ Hope it works.